# Android intent getting the context

Tags: android, android-intent

I am just curious as to what the code below does? I am learning about Intents at the moment.

```
Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), Viewmap.class);
```

Am I right to think that this is creating an Intent object that will start up the Viewmap class and the getContext() method will inform the Viewmap class of where the intent came from?? I guess I'm more confused as to what v.getContext is actually doing. (v is View object).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am just curious as to what the code below does?

It creates an [`Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) which is launched from the [`Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) containing `v`. This `Intent`'s target is `Viewmap`'s class (which should be an `Activity` registered in the manifest, in this case).

> Am I right to think that this is creating an Intent object that will start up the Viewmap class and the getContext() method will inform the Viewmap class of where the intent came from??

Close. The `Context` you provide notifies the system which package to find the `Viewmap` class in.

> I guess I'm more confused as to what v.getContext is actually doing.

It is just returning the `Context` through which `v` is implemented. The `Context` contains things like package name, resource identifiers, and so on. The documentation describes it as an "*[i]nterface to global information about an application environment. ... It allows access to application-specific resources and classes, as well as up-calls for application-level operations such as launching activities, broadcasting and receiving intents, etc.*".